# jQuery not working in Chrome and IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Wordpress theme.
On the header I check if this is the first visit (the user just entered the website).

If this is the first visit, an animation appears. Animation = a sidebar appears in the middle of the page, in some miliseconds it opens and the page appears.
In the code, ub_sb_closed_on_hp is an option that sets only the sidebar to appear for the home page.

It works under Mozilla, but it doesn't work under Internet Explorer and Chrome. On IE and Chrome the animation appears on all the pages.

See the code here: http://paste.laravel.com/lFt

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is that the session is not working, and the problem isn't that the jQuery isn't working? To test this, put `print "I'm in the session condition.";` just inside your session condition.

Comment: Interesting.. if I insert that the page doesn't load :) - any idea why?

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize that that condition was wrapped by a jQuery statement. Do `die("I'm in the session");` instead `print`.

Comment: die works under php, but the text "i'm in the session" doesn't appear

Comment: So you have `<?php //IF FIRST VISIT if($_SESSION['first_time_here'] == ''): die("I'm in the session");`?

Comment: yes, and the "die" it is working, but the text doesn't appear (that's probably because of php from jquery)

Comment: I'm not sure why your text isn't appearing, but it's as I figured - it's not the `$_SESSION` that's your problem, it's the jQuery. I don't see a problem with it, but maybe someone else can get your answer.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code here in your question
?

Comment: see the code here: http://paste.laravel.com/lFt  (or are you talking about something else? what relevant code?)

Comment: You are mixing serverside and clientside code? (You have PHP-code wrapped inside the jQuery-code)

Comment: can you include the code like it is shown in the browser? (i.e. not the code mixing js and php?)

Comment: It's a theme, it's not developed by me, I just have to fix these issues.. (nice.. :D). Jamie - you're talking about "View page source"? Or about all the code from this page, header.php?

Comment: yes, talking about "view page source". And can you also check the console in Chrome for any error messages? To access the console, click right anywhere in the page and choose "inspect element" from the menu.  See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console?hl=de#opening_the_console for further information.

Comment: no errors in Chrome Console. Here is the page Source Code: http://paste.laravel.com/lFX

Comment: this is much code - but I believe that the function call in line 67 does not work, remove it, you don't need it since your animation is inside of document.ready. Check out this simplified code in http://jsfiddle.net/FWDvX/

Comment: i'll test it right now, hope it helps removing that function

Comment: still not working, if I remove that function, the loader is displayed, and the page doesn't load any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code is good. The issue is fixed now.

The problem was that I commented a line of code that was inserting an image. 
This wordpress theme is developed in a strange way (search for empire if interested).

Thanks all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```
        if ($_SESSION['first_time_here'] == ''):

            //SET PAGE TO CLOSED FOR OPENING
            if (get_option('ub_sb_closed_on_hp') != 'yes'){                     
//              print " 
?>
                if (jQuery(window).width() > 980){              
                    jQuery('#page').css({'display':'inline','width':'300px','overflow':'hidden','margin-right':'340px'});
                    jQuery('#sidebar').css({'margin-left':'326px'});
                }
//              ";
    <?php
            }
        ?>
```

and also:

```
                    if (get_option('ub_sb_closed_on_hp') != 'yes'){                     
                    ?>
//                      print "
                        if (jQuery(window).width() > 980){                                      
                            jQuery('#sidebar').delay(800).animate({'margin-left':'0px'},2100);      
                            jQuery('#page').delay(800).animate({'margin-right':'0px','width':'666px'},2100);                
                        }                                               
//                      ";
<?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

Edit 1: I could not see, where you initialize `$_SESSION['first_time_here']`. if you did not initialize it, you can try below changes

Find: `if($_SESSION['first_time_here'] == ''):`

Replace: `if (!isset($_SESSION['first_time_here'])):`

Comment: I will try and get back with and answer a little later, thanks